# How to reset index to 0 in every multiple of 4?

Tags: javascript, logic

What I have is a dynamic list of `<li>` tags. Each of this `<li>` has an index number (which naturally starts with 0). The index or list could go up to 100+.

On hover, I need to display/get the current li's index but the index number needs to reset to 0, 1, 2, 3 in every multiple of 4. For instance:

```
index - 0, 1, 2, 3 on hover should reset to 0, 1, 2, 3
index - 4, 5, 6, 7 on hover should reset to 0, 1, 2, 3
index - 8, 9, 10, 11 on hover should reset to 0, 1, 2, 3
```

... and so on and so forth.

Can anyone help me on how to reset the indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the modulo operator:

```
index = index % 4;
```